# Why is my redis key expired ahead of expire time?

Tags: redis, phpredis

I set up a redis key and set its expire time to a week:

```
$expireTime = 7*24*3600;

$redis->hSet($redisKey, $uniqueId, 1);
$redis->expire($redisKey, $expireTime);
```

But I found the key may be expired in several days, not a week. It is very unacceptable for me.

Does it expired since the key-value is too large?

How to keep my redis key lives as long as I expected?

My `max-memory` setting is 4G, `used_memory_peak_human` is 2.06G, and eviction policy is the default setting `volatile-lru`.

Comment: I'm assuming your machine's internal clock isn't messed up or something right?

Comment: What is `$expireTime`'s value?

Comment: @ItamarHaber 7*24*3600=604800

Comment: @shafeen my machine's clock is ok

Comment: Are you running out of memory? Depending on your eviction settings, this could also be a cause.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Memory is ok. Memory usage is less than 30 percent.

Comment: @jason I think Itamar Haber was referring to the max-memory settings, and your eviction policy (what happens when you've reach max-memory). Check your conf to find max-memory, and check the used memory with info.

Comment: @Pixou My max-memory setting is 4G, `used_memory_peak_human` is 2.06G, eviction policy is the default setting `volatile-lru`

Comment: @JasonCao: just to sanity check, when you say “several days”, you don’t mean “seven days” do you?

Comment: Did you change the date/time in your Server?